# Git doesn't clone content of template directory

Tags: git, githooks

I want to have something like a post-clone hook.
So my idea was to create a template directory in my remote origin which contains a "hooks" folder and a "post-checkout"-script within.

So my "post-checkout"-script is located in the remote origin at:

```
[remote-repo-path]/template/hooks/post-checkout
```

Next, I configure the template directory in the remote origin:

```
git config init.templatedir '[remote-repo-path]/template'
```

But... when I clone from the repository I only get the stuff from the default templatedir on my local machine.

How can I clone the template directory from my remote origin?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `[remote-repo-path]` here, but Git can only access *local* files when copying a template directory during `git init`.

Comment: Those are the configurations on the git server I want to clone from. I'm doing the git config init.templatedir on the server, because I thought the templatedir was cloned to the local .git directory..... I think I misunderstood the idea of templates in git, i thought it was ment to be a template for behaviour or actions being performed on specific git command... I guess it is more about some directory structure...?

Comment: OK, I think I see where the confusing bit is now.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to realize here that Git is *extremely* biased about where it gets stuff.  In particular, what Git calls *templates* **must** exist on the *local* system.  Configuration data, including control knobs that can be set in `.git/config` and `.git/hooks/*`, is always<sup>1</sup> found locally.  This way, cloning a repository does not introduce a [Trojan horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_(computing)).

What this means is that the *server's* templates, if any exist, are irrelevant.  Your `git clone` command can be thought of as running the following six mostly-Git commands:<sup>2</sup>

1. `mkdir path`, to create a new directory that will hold a repository; the rest of the commands are then run in that new directory.  The *`path`* is from your clone command.
2. `git init`, to create an initial, totally-empty repository
3. `git remote add remote url`, where *`remote`* is normally `origin` and *`url`* is the URL you used in the clone command.
4. `git config` if/as needed (only if some optional arguments are given to `git clone`).
5. `git fetch remote`, to obtain commits and other Git objects from the remote added in step 3, and create remote-tracking names for their Git's branch names.
6. `git checkout name`, where *`name`* is from your `-b` option, or as directed by the other Git during step 5 if you did not provide a `-b` option.

The only one of these steps that uses a template is step 2, and at step 2, your Git has not even contacted the server yet.  So any hook files or other data copied in during step 2 must necessarily come from files on your own machine, not on the server.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some minor exceptions to this rule.  For instance, Git's *submodule* data can be copied from a repository's `.gitmodules` file to `.git/config`.  Such data must be carefully vetted to avoid security issues.  Git should do this careful vetting on its own; if it fails to do so, that's a bug.

<sup>2</sup>Some of these six commands can sometimes be omitted, depending on what options you might pass to `git clone`, and the clone code has all of this stuff built into it, rather than being a simple shell script that just runs each of the commands in turn.  But the effect is *as if* you ran these commands.